# Double Adverb Use e.g. *equally shockingly*

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Yesterday, my biology instructor said (I'm paraphrasing here): "Shockingly, this cell does blah blah blah, and *equally shockingly*, the cell blah blah blah." Is this proper grammar (I speak American English incase that is important to know)?

Comment: First, be aware that EL&U has a very strong descriptivist bent, so almost every question which starts with "**Is it correct...?**" is answered with "***Yes.***" (on the most outlandish usages, you might get "*Sure, why not? You understood him, didn't you?*"). With that said, while "*equally shockingly*" is fine by that measure, I personally would have phrased it "*equally shocking*" (and secretly would prefer your biology teacher did too).

Comment: In order to avoid suggestions of 'proofreading' (which is explicitly off-topic), you might say what you think the problem is. An adverb modifying an adverb? A comma splice (as in your description, but not necessarily the original)?

Comment: There have been moves to name the adverb- (and adjective-) modifier usages (really slowly ... // fast asleep ...) more realistically. The term 'degree modifier' is often used with intensifiers (very slowly), attenuators (fairly quickly) and doubtless comparators (equally worryingly). With modifiers having semantic content of their own (brutally honest / calculatedly rude / chillingly effective / confusingly silent / cunningly concealed / dangerously ill ...) 'secondary modifiers' may be the preferred term. They are many and common, and usually end in -ly.

Comment: Why would you suspect that a second or further more adverbs would be ungrammatical? Compare with adjectives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/adverbs) says it is correct (emphasis mine):

> An adverb is a word that’s used to give information about a verb, adjective, or **other adverb**.

So unless this is challenged with arguments, I would see no reason to see *equally shockingly* as anything but correct, even if it may be rarely used.

Comment: Doesn't that make the Q a GR?

Comment: @Kris, actually, I think it does indeed.

Comment: I disagree. I think it's high time the adverb dustbin was emptied, and its contents sorted through and recycled. There's a lot of good stuff that needs repackaging.